# MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException while deploying to APIGEE using Maven

Tags: maven, deployment, apigee

I am trying to deploy code to APIGEE using Maven.

While trying out the example available at APIGEE's page on Github, I get this response -

~~~~~~

```
=============Now zipping the App Bundle================


[INFO]
[INFO] <<< apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (deploy-bundle) < package @ for
ecastweatherapi <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (deploy-bundle) @ forecastweath
erapi ---
[INFO]

=============Initializing Maven Deployment================


[INFO]

=============Importing App================


[ERROR]


* * * * * * * * * * *

This deployment could have failed for a variety of reasons.



* * * * * * * * * * *



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.171 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-19T12:12:36+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-ma
ven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (deploy-bundle) on project forecastweatherapi: MojoExecu
tionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing authentication information -when you run the pom file.

Comment: After I provide the authentication information, I get a Connection Refused exception.